# Matlab montage color spaces

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Given an image I need to try different color spaces which match the montage below:

[image]

```
RGB = imread('image.jpg');
montage(RGB)
```

However what I reach is a montage of grey channels!

---

EDIT:
We can montage 4 images, the original one and the three colored channels, as below:

```
RGB = imread('image.jpg');
R = RGB(:,:,1);
G = RGB(:,:,2);
B = RGB(:,:,3);
redCh = cat(3, R, zeros(size(G), 'uint8'), zeros(size(B), 'uint8'));
greenCh = cat(3, zeros(size(R), 'uint8'), G, zeros(size(B), 'uint8'));
blueCh = cat(3, zeros(size(R), 'uint8'), zeros(size(G), 'uint8'), B);
%
montage({RGB,redCh,greenCh,blueCh})
```

However the montage is still far from what I intend to create!

Comment: But you dont even have 4 images in the code you show, how do you expect to show 4 images?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I'm new to image processing and I don't know how to reproduce the montage above. @AnderBiguri

Comment: Unfortunately that is too broad of a question. I suggest giving it a go with different methods, reading a bit about it until you are not new to image processing and then asking the question. "How to do this project" is generally frowned upon in stackoverflow, as it seems that you are asking us to do your work (which I assume you are not, but that is the impression it gives).

Comment: Thank you for comment. Please see my edited post. @AnderBiguri

Comment: Thanks! the code looks well, better fitted for the webpage. However, it is unlikely that anyone can reverse engineer which exact transformations happened on those color images. Do you have no description of how the ones you show were created? They are clearly not just the R,G,B channels, they are some particular mixture of the three, nor sure which

Comment: Merci, I have no extra description. What I know is that there is a color space that produce that montage! @AnderBiguri

Comment: There are infinite color spaces, we can not guess from an infinite set

Comment: Yes exactly! +1 But I'm waiting maybe someone know that color space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! So simple..

```
% Convert RGB color values to HSV color space
HSV = rgb2hsv(RGB);
% Convert RGB color values to NTSC color space
NTSC = rgb2ntsc(RGB);
% Convert RGB color values to YCbCr color space
YCbCr = rgb2ycbcr(RGB);
%
montage({RGB,HSV,NTSC,YCbCr}, 'Size', [2 2]);
```